# Select data from table1 and copy it to table2

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am a real novice in c#.

I have seen many questions like this over here. But, on trying, I could not get my code.

I want all the columns of a row to be retrieved and then transfer it to another table of same database.

So basically, retrieve data from `table1` and copy it to the respective columns of `table2`.

I have tried this much code.
And I am confused as how to call directly check string instead of defining each column in str1 string in the " ".

```
 string check = "select * from custdetails where billid = @billid ";

         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(check , conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billid", billid);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        da.Fill(ds);
       // string str1;
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            string str1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][""].ToString();
        }
```

I really dont have much idea about c#.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you need to modify or use the data for anything else in the application? If not, why don't you do this in one command.

Comment: Are you trying to construct an `INSERT` statement to put data in your `table2`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by using :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM  table1 WHERE billid = @billid)
```

the above is gud only when `table1` & `table2` had same structure. In case both table has different structure you need to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT [COLUMNS ,]...`

One you are done Copying the Data then you can carry on with reading data into you application

```
string check = "select * from custdetails where billid = @billid ";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
// use the command object to copy table first....
cmd1.Connection = conn;
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM  table1 WHERE billid = @billid)";
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

//then continue doing the normal work
cmd1.CommandText = check;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billid", billid);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
da.Fill(ds);
// string str1;
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (count > 0)
{
    string str1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][""].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This really helped... but I get an error as wrong syntax near keyword select. Must declare scalar variable "@billid"

Answer (score 1):

> You can achieve it by the following line.

```
INSERT INTO targettable
SELECT * FROM custdetails WHERE billid = @billid;
```